# Linear Algebra, find determinant with x1, x2,...,xn as scalars

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[image]

I have no clue how to even begin solving for $\det(A)$ since $n$ is unknown, HELP!

Answer (score 2):

If $n=1$ or $n=2$ then you can calculate the determinant explicitly. If $n> 2$, then take the difference of the first two rows and the difference of the first row and third row. You will get $(x_1-x_2,\ldots,x_1-x_2)$ and $(x_1-x_3,\ldots,x_1-x_3)$ which are linearly dependent (both multiples of $(1,,\ldots,1)$), so the first three rows are linearly dependent and thus the determinant is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $C_i$ the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of $A$ then we have

$$C_3-C_1=2(C_2-C_1)$$
hence the columns are linearly dependent and then the determinant is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly
\begin{align}
\det\,\left(\begin{matrix}
x_1+1 & x_1+2 & \cdots & x_1+n \\
x_2+1 & x_2+2 & \cdots & x_2+n \\
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_n+1 & x_n+2 & \cdots & x_n+n
\end{matrix}\right)&=
\det\,\left(\begin{matrix}
x_1+1 & 1 & x_1+3&\cdots & x_1+n \\
x_2+1 & 1 & x_2+3&\cdots & x_2+n \\
\cdots & \cdots& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_n+1 & 1 & x_n+3&\cdots & x_n+n
\end{matrix}\right) \\ {} \\&=
\det\,\left(\begin{matrix}
x_1+1 & 1 & 2&\cdots & x_1+n \\
x_2+1 & 1 & 2&\cdots & x_2+n \\
\cdots & \cdots& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
x_n+1 & 1 & 2&\cdots & x_n+n
\end{matrix}\right)=0.
\end{align}
In the first equality we subtracted the first column from the second one, while in the second equality we subtracted the first column form the third one. The determinant of the last matrix is equal to zero as the third column is a multiple of the second one.